# Is there a way to access what the current language uses for zero?

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, internationalization, nsnumberformatter

Instead of using `"0"`, I'm trying to figure out how to access what the current user's language uses for zero.

In the `NumberFormatter` documentation, `zeroSymbol` is `nil` until explicitly set.

Is there a way to set `zeroSymbol` to the current language's zero?

Comment: zeroSymbol is the same for all languages "0" and that's what you get if you don't set this property

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm getting `nil`, and haven't set the property?

Comment: Kkkk and that’s correct. I meant when using string(for:) method

Comment: @LeoDabus `po formatter.string(for: formatter.zeroSymbol)` shows `""` - are you saying that it should show `"0"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zeroSymbol` property doesn't do what you think it does. Per the documentation (the next and only sentence after the one you mentioned ;-)):

> You might, for example, set this property to " - " in a spreadsheet used for accounting.

Comment: Ha, yup! The only thing is, in the debugger, I'm seeing `formatter.zeroSymbol` is `nil`, and I haven't set it.

Comment: Yes, that's the point the docs are making. It's `nil` (which means it will use `0`) unless you set it, then it will use the string you provided. It's only for when you want to override `0` with something else (such as the example the docs state: using a dash to represent `0`, a standard sometimes used in accounting). In other words, it's not meant for localization as you assumed but for *overriding* `0` in special cases.

Comment: That part makes sense - the part I'm struggling with is how to access either a string or integer (or number) representation of `0`, if the formatter is using `0` by default?

Comment: `formatter.string(from: 0)` ? That covers default 0 as well as any cases where you didn’t realize you set a substitution. I’m not really sure any more I get what you’re asking here. Since this has nothing to do with localization, there’s nothing unknown here. Either you as the developer set a substitution for that particular number formatter instance or you didn’t.

Comment: This is exactly what we were looking for and arrived at, in case there are languages who's string representation of zero aren't `0`. Thanks!